# Why is there typically no psychiatric assessment involved when applying for Visas?

Tags: visa

I see it that for many visa that we have to apply for in this world, it is simply asked some formalities of the document. They typically would ask also over travel history, in hopes to get assurance that we are not going to the country with ill intent. Then, why is it that psychiatric testing for people who want to travel into other countries is not normalized?

Comment: Because psychiatric testing itself is not 'normalized'.

Comment: This is a weird question. What kind of "psychiatric testing" do you think should be performed and how? And what benefit would you expect from that? What kinds of "ill intent" do you think could be detected that way?

Comment: Let's say terrorist intent or something. Whatever the hell they're trying to figure out by asking stuff like asking if you visited certain middle eastern countries @Philipp

Comment: @SBrian Terrorist intent is not a psychiatric issue and will not show up in psychiatric testing.

Comment: @SBrian How would you perform a "psychiatric test" that tells you whether or not a person is a terrorist? Mind reading devices have not been invented yet, AFAIK.

Answer (score 7):

It's going to boil down to two things:

1. Psychiatric testing is complicated, expensive and invasive. To routinely implement such tests would cost a lot, slow down the visa process, and be considered massively offensive by the many many people visiting a country for perfectly normal reasons.
2. Instances of those with psychiatric issues coming to countries and causing trouble because of that are extremely rare. You would be spending a lot of money to fix hardly any problems.

It should be noted that some kinds of visas, especially immigration visas, do require a medical examination and it would be expected that at least obvious or already-diagnosed mental issues would be reported as part of that.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the [previous answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/80642/21531)

Anyone who has to support someone who struggles, or who themself struggles, with mental health issues and who has been confronted with the reality of long wait times, *even when paying out of pocket, let alone when asking for universal health coverage* would find such a diversion of scarce qualified professionals, for unclear reasons ("terrorists" are not necessarily catchable here), a complete travesty, most specifically when it comes to visitor visas.

Many self-respecting professionals in the field would, I assume, also object to carrying out such a pointless job.

Nor would it catch people from visa-free countries.

Immigration procedures are something else and as noted a) yes some request medical affidavit of health and b) many also request reports of clean criminal records.

Criminal record status, a rather more relevant flag to visitor security issues, *can be* a factor in visa application:  SE.Travel frequently gets such questions.

Last, you can bet the tourism industry for the implementing country would also oppose it vigorously - who the heck would visit such an inhospitable host country???